# Multiple Custom UITableViewCell using in tableView(_cellForRowAt:)

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have some custom UITableViewCell,and would using some of them randomly. But after I register them ,it will crashed in `tableView(_cellForRowAt:)`.
Here is my code:
  in viewDidLoad method

```
    tableView.register(CustomACell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Identifier")
    tableView.register(CustomACell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Identifier")

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let model = dataSource[indexPath.row]
    if let type = model.type {
        switch type {
        case .A:
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: MyIdentifier) as! CustomACell
            cell.assgin(message: model)
            return cell

        case .B:
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: MyIdentifier) as! CustomBCell
            cell.assgin(message: model)
            return cell
        }
    }
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: MyIdentifier) as! CustomACell
    cell.assgin(message: model)
    return cell
}
```

If I register both ,it will crashed at case .A. If I won't, some of them would crash at `tableView.dequeueReusableCell`.
Here is one of the console error info:

***Could not cast value of type 'TM.CustomACell' (0x10bb40940) to 'TM.CustomBCell' (0x10bb40578).***

Comment: Did you have all customCell in storyboard ?

Comment: there is just a tableview with no cell in SB @Surjeet

Comment: and how you are creating CustomACell, CustomBCell, etc .. ? They have separate xib files or doing to programatically.

Comment: @Surjeet just using the code inherit UITableViewCell

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the CellReuseIdentifiers. You use same for both custom cells. Use diffrent identifires for diffrent cells.

[image]

```
var nibName = UINib(nibName: "Identifier1", bundle: nil)
        self.tableView.register(nibName, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Identifier")

nibName = UINib(nibName: "Identifier2", bundle: nil)
        self.tableView.register(nibName, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Identifier2")
```

Then change the cellForRowAt, try following code

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let model = dataSource[indexPath.row]
    if let type = model.type {
        switch type {
        case .A:
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Identifier1") as! CustomACell
            cell.assgin(message: model)
            return cell

        case .B:
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Identifier2") as! CustomBCell
            cell.assgin(message: model)
            return cell
       default : 
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Identifier1") as! CustomACell
            cell.assgin(message: model)
            return cell
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works for me. And is there any shortcut method. I have many many custom cell, if so, the code seems to be clumsy.

Answer (score 1):

if you created a separate `Nib`, then you can register else no need to register

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) ->UITableViewCell{

     var cell = UITableViewCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: "pgIdentifier")

     if (XXX == true) {

           let pgtcell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "indetifier", for: indexPath) as! CustomCell1
     } else {

          let pgtcell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "indetifier", for: indexPath) as! MyCustomCell1

     }
}
```